# How can map cosntructor can be use in the form of class compare?

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor

When I was  reading the reference for map container at cplusplus.com, I figured out that there are 5 ways of using its constructor. I understood how to use  empty container constructors, range constructor, copy constructor.
But what about move constructor and initializer list constructor?

Here's an example of using map constructor. How did the fourth and fifth constructed and what are their element.

```
// constructing maps
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

bool fncomp (char lhs, char rhs) {return lhs<rhs;}

struct classcomp {
   bool operator() (const char& lhs, const char& rhs) const
   {return lhs<rhs;}
};

int main ()
{
   std::map<char,int> first;

   first['a']=10;
   first['b']=30;
   first['c']=50;
   first['d']=70;

   std::map<char,int> second (first.begin(),first.end());

   std::map<char,int> third (second);

   std::map<char,int,classcomp> fourth;                 // class as Compare

   bool(*fn_pt)(char,char) = fncomp;
   std::map<char,int,bool(*)(char,char)> fifth (fn_pt); // function pointer as Compare

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand your sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth constructor overload is a *move constructor*.  Move semantics are basically a way of stealing resources from *temporary* objects which are about to be destroyed.

If you wrote a function which returned a `std::map`, and attempted to initialize a new one via the return value, as in:

```
std:: map <char, int> f ();
map <char, int> new_map (f());
```

`new_map` would be *move constructed* from the result of `f`.

You can find a fantastic explanation of "rvalue references" and "move semantics" [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).

The *initializer-list* constructor uses the new brace-initialization syntax and might look like this:

```
std:: map <char, char> TranslationTable {{'G', 'C'}, {'C', 'G'}, 
                                         {'T', 'A'}, {'A', 'T'}};
```

Comment: +1    Excellent answer, but what does this line in the example code do. `std::map<char,int,classcomp> fourth;`

Comment: In the reference's example code, `classcomp` is a type which is used to sort the elements in the map.  By default it is `std::less`.  See the entry on the reference page under "comp".